# Robolectric 3.2.2 cannot access Icon

Tags: android, robolectric

So I tried to migrate from Robolectric 3.1-rc1 to Robolectric 3.2.2. Whenever I want to build my Android Project, i get the following error:

```
error: cannot access Icon
        Intent lastStartedActivity = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
                                     ^
  class file for android.graphics.drawable.Icon not found
```

The error pops up in my first Test class.
I have no idea what I have done wrong. My Testclasses use a custom TestRunner that extends from RobolectricTestRunner and override the buildGlobalConfig() method as follows:

```
@Override protected Config buildGlobalConfig() {
    return new Config.Builder().setSdk(21).setManifest(Config.DEFAULT_MANIFEST_NAME).setQualifiers(Config.DEFAULT_QUALIFIERS)
            .setPackageName(Config.DEFAULT_PACKAGE_NAME).setResourceDir(Config.DEFAULT_RES_FOLDER).setAssetDir(Config.DEFAULT_ASSET_FOLDER)
            .setBuildDir(Config.DEFAULT_BUILD_FOLDER).setConstants(BuildConfig.class).build();
}
```

Maybe some Robolectric expert can help?

Comment: Are you sure that you're posting the correct error line? There is no mentioning of the icon in that line

Comment: I have seen this issue as well with Robolectric 3.2.2. My tests were running fine before. @EugenMartynov I think this error is thrown if you have a test that uses shadow classes and its methods regardless of the test you run. I was running a test which doesn't have Shadows usage and i still see this error. Error source points to shadowOf() line in some other test.

Comment: I think recently I saw same error and issue was wrong working directory while running tests in AS